# Fast and best way to restore large local DB in IaaS SQL Azure

Tags: sql, azure, database-restore

I googled but did not find an answer.

Could you please help me what's the best way to restore  large bak (bakcup) database from local DEV machine to SQL Azure hosted in IaaS? It's a proper SQL server hosted in Azure VM.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a drive locally and then copy the bak file onto the drive. I would then upload the drive to azure storage and then mount the drive to the vm and restore the bak file.

Comment: can you please clarify "create drive locally". Does it mean local laptop? Also, what do you mean "copy the bak file to drive". Lastly please clarify "mount the drive to VM".

Answer (score 0):

Create a virtual hard drive (VHD) file on your on premises server

Copy SQL Server data files or setup bits to the VHD file

Create and install a management certificate

Upload the VHD file to Azure using Add-AzureVHD

Access SQL Server data files or setup bits in Azure virtual machine.

msdn has a detailed post on this.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn133153.aspx